# Using object's member instead of object itself when calling object

Tags: javascript

Here's the class and object:

```
class BDImage
{
    constructor(path)
    {
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = path;
    }
}

var myImage = new BDImage("path/to/image.png");
```

I want to access/use `myImage`'s `img` member without typing `myImage.img` all the time. Instead just `myImage` and then I'm actually referring to `myImage.img`.

How?

Comment: The language provides no facility to make that possible. You can always make another variable, or re-assign `myImage` to `myImage.img`.

Comment: You can declare another variable within the context in which it'll be used so that you can have  var img = myImage.img;

Comment: @Pointy check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty - its possible ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz that's a nice trick but it's not what the OP asked; I agree that it's what the OP can do to satisfy the original desire, but it's not a lot different from having a separate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## extends ;)

```js
    class BDImage extends Image
    {
        constructor(path)
        {
            super()
            this.src = path
        }
    }

    var myImage = new BDImage("path/to/image.png");
    console.log(myImage, myImage.src);
```

## [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
class BDImage
{
    constructor(path)
    {
        this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = path
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'src', {
          get(){
            return this.image.src;
          },
          set(path){
            this.image.src = path
          }
       })
    }
}
myImage = new BDImage("path/to/image.png");
console.log(myImage, myImage.src);

myImage.image.src = "path/to/image2.png"
console.log(myImage, myImage.src);

myImage.src = "path/to/image3.png"
console.log(myImage, myImage.src);
```

Comment: `extends` is just what I need. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Just cache the reference in a variable:

```js
class BDImage
{
    constructor(path)
    {
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = path;
    }
}

var myImage = new BDImage("path/to/image.png");

var imgProp = myImage.img;  // Now imgProp points to myImage.img

console.log(imgProp.src);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need some **Functional programming** !

```
function BDImage(path) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = path; 
    return img;
}; 

const myImage = BDImage("path/img.png");
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: How does this address the question that was asked?

Comment: It is exactly the result that was asked in an elegant alternative, even if it's using a function instead of a class.

Comment: Uh, no it's not. The question was how to be able to access `myImage.img` without having to type that and instead typing something simpler, like: `myImage`. The question had nothing to do with functions. `"I want to access/use myImage's img member without typing myImage.img all the time. Instead just myImage and then I'm actually using myImage.img."` In your code, you'd still have to write `myImage.src`.

Comment: Yeah, he write `myImage.src` instead of `myImage.img.src` as the function is directly return the `img` reference. Which is exactly what every other answers in the thread is doing.